# Django ManytoMany retireving all objects that fulfill a condition simoultaneously

Tags: django, orm, manytomanyfield

Using the Django models examples on querymaking (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/):

How can I select all the entries that have ALL of it's author's names starting with R using the filter function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the double-underscore syntax, as described [further down that page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
Entry.objects.filter(authors__name__startswith='R')
```

**Edit**

So what you actually want to do is to exclude all those authors who do *not* start with R. You could do that with a Q object and the `~` operator:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Entry.objects.exclude(~Q(authors__name__startswith='R'))
```

Comment: I think what he meant was all of the authors for a entry post have to have their names start with R, not just one or some of them.

Comment: Yes, I meant what Cheng said.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman, But for the purpose of avoiding to have to rewrite a lot of already implemented code, Do you think that there is a way of doing the same using the filterfunction (not exclude) as stated in the question?

Comment: How would adding a possibly complex filter function require less rewriting than changing it to exclude? They both return a queryset.

Comment: The thing is, I pass a lot of conditions to that filter (as a string) and the one that I am trying to achieve It's just another one.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a one tricky solution for such a task. *(not tested)*

```
Entry.objects \
    .annotate(num_authors=Count('authors')) \
    .filter(authors__name__startswith='R')
    .annotate(num_authors_with_r=Count('authors')) \
    .filter(num_authors=F('num_authors_with_r'))
```

What's the idea?

1. We get the count of all authors.
2. Do filter
3. Return only rows with filtered authors count == all authors count

Comment: Thanks, but tried this approach and got all the entries I had inserted even though that they authors with their name not starting with R

Comment: I guess this can [eventually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) be considered as a `django-bug`, however I would advice you to use the **@Daniel Roseman** solution. It's far better than this one even if it worked.